# How do i save cmd output to an already made folder or Directory?

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to save `cmd` output to a folder, but receiving `Access is denied.` even though I'm using an admin profile and even put command prompt in admin mode.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show profile HUAWEI-B315-719B key=clear >> C:\Users\kuku\Desktop\Creations
Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably fails because `C:\Users\kuku\Desktop\Creations` is a folder.

You should output to a file like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show profile HUAWEI-B315-719B key=clear >> C:\Users\kuku\Desktop\Creations\output.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Run your CMD as an Administrator, if you are getting Access Denied error. 
And Secondly, specify the file in which you do want to write output under `C:\Users\kuku\Desktop\Creations` directory. For example:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show profile HUAWEI-B315-719B key=clear >> C:\Users\kuku\Desktop\Creations\output.txt
```

**Note:** Use `>` to overwrite the output to a file and use `>>` to append the output to a file.

Comment: There is no sudo on windows.

Comment: Yeah, if OS is windows then CMD needs to be run as an administrator.